# Why can`t i import this CSV file from my computer into my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to import a csv file into my jupyter notebook online but i get an error message

````py
import pandas as pd
Goo = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\Users\Arcsa\Desktop\EXCEL\GOOG") 
​
print(type(goo))
​```
​
  File "<ipython-input-3-7df5486c9aa2>", line 1
    Goo = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\Users\Arcsa\Desktop\EXCEL\GOOG")
                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
````

Answer (score 0):

the `\` char is escaping whats after it... and specifically `\U` tried to convert it to a Character with 32-bit hex value, as per [String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) docs

try using raw string for the path:

```py
import pandas as pd
Goo = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(r"C:\Users\Arcsa\Desktop\EXCEL\GOOG") 
​
print(type(goo))
```

Comment: No w it gives me the following message: import pandas as pd

​

​

​

​

Goo = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\Users\Arcsa\Desktop\EXCEL\GOOG") 

​

print(type(goo))

  File "<ipython-input-7-ea8f9313346b>", line 1
    Goo = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\Users\Arcsa\Desktop\EXCEL\GOOG")
                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: where is the `r` before the string quote? Did you use my code?